# Button going outside of container div when it should have enough space to fit inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make tabs at the top of a div, and I'm trying to make whichever tab has the .selected class be taller than the rest, but for some reason the selected tab is leaving the container div instead of using the space it has, which I'm pretty sure is the same height as the button including padding and margin.

CSS:

```css
.tabContainer {
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 35px;
}

.tab {
    border: 0;
    background: #88B7B5;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.tab.selected {
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    transition: height 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;
}

.tab:hover {
    background: #98cdca;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}

.tabContentsContainer { margin-top: 0; }

.tabContents {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #A7CAB1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
    <button class="tab selected" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">Inventory</button>
    <button class="tab" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="location">Location</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="research">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="recruits">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="training">???</button>
</div>
<div class="tabContentsContainer">
    <div class="tabContents" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">
        <h1>Inventory</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular block-level element (a non-flex item) Usually follows the box model, which allows overflow by default.

If a regular child item’s content exceeds the size of its parent container, it will overflow unless you specify otherwise with the overflow property.

> If you follow Musawar ahmeds  advice & set `overflow: hidden;` inside `.tabContainer` you will solve the problem.

However I would like to point out that using the flex feature to control the design & behavior of groups of elements like Poseidon27 commented is generally easier than struggling with positioning of rogue elements.

The example uses the flex property without overflowing:

```css
.tabContainer {
    display: flex;             /* Make this div a flex container */
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tab {
    border: 0;
    background: #88B7B5;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    
    
    /* Set margin for all tab elements */
    margin: auto 1px;  
    
    
    /* override bottom margin to eliminate the space below the NOT SELECTED tabs */
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}


.tab.selected {
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    transition: height 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;
}

.tab:hover {
    background: #98cdca;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}

.tabContentsContainer { margin-top: 0; }

.tabContents {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #A7CAB1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
    <button class="tab selected" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">Inventory</button>
    <button class="tab" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="location">Location</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="research">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="recruits">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="training">???</button>
</div>
<div class="tabContentsContainer">
    <div class="tabContents" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">
        <h1>Inventory</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[BTW](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) : By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box.

If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen.

This means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.

For example, if you have four boxes with width: 25%;, if any has left or right padding or a left or right border, they will not by default fit on one line within the constraints of the parent container.

Ps. I also removed a few redundant properties in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

> You just need to add overflow hidden in navbar div

```css
.tabContainer {
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 35px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.tab {
    border: 0;
    background: #88B7B5;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.tab.selected {
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    transition: height 0.2s, margin-top 0.2s;
}

.tab:hover {
    background: #98cdca;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}

.tabContentsContainer { margin-top: 0; }

.tabContents {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #A7CAB1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
    <button class="tab selected" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">Inventory</button>
    <button class="tab" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="location">Location</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="research">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="recruits">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="training">???</button>
</div>
<div class="tabContentsContainer">
    <div class="tabContents" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">
        <h1>Inventory</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex-box or grid (if not familiar, check out some of the tutorials) it will make your coding much easier and much more responsive. Also, don't use static units like Pixels, instead use em or rem. One of the reasons your tab is going outside of the div is because you didn't specify the width of it, therefore it is inheriting (default).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add some css styles to the `tabContainer` class which are as below:

`display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; gap: 8px;`

as you need to align all tabs at bottom and while `.selected` class is applied tab should have 5px more hight compare to other tabs and also need to bottom aligned you have to make parent `display: flex;` to align them and `gap` is to give spaces between tabs.

for the transition, you can simply add `transition:  all 0.2s ease;` as you `all` will consider all properties for the transition no need to add each property individually for the same.

also I've added `height: 35px` to the `.tab:hover` as well for better UI/UX.

Please refer below snippet for your query.

```css
.tabContainer {
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 8px;
}

.tab {
    border: 0;
    background: #88B7B5;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}

.tab.selected {
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    transition:  all 0.2s ease;
}

.tab:hover {
    height: 35px;
    background: #98cdca;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transition:  all 0.2s ease;
}

.tabContentsContainer { margin-top: 0; }

.tabContents {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #A7CAB1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabContainer">
    <button class="tab selected" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">Inventory</button>
    <button class="tab" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="location">Location</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="research">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="recruits">???</button>
    <button class="tab locked" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="training">???</button>
</div>
<div class="tabContentsContainer">
    <div class="tabContents" data-tabgroup="main" data-tab="inventory">
        <h1>Inventory</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```